# Can an Onen receive an Aliyah?

Tags: death, torah-reading, mourning-aveilus

By onen I mean someone who as lost their sibling, and they haven't been buried yet.

Can an onen be called to the Torah as an Oleh? Can an onen read from the Torah?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In response to both your queries:

> but [an onen] does not act as Chazzan, read the Torah, or receive an Aliyah

from [here](http://www.askmoses.com/en/article/165,2068564/What-are-the-obligations-and-exemptions-of-an-Onan.html).

Even if the only Kohen in shul is an onen, he still [doesn't get an Aliyah](http://www.yeshiva.org.il/ask/eng/?id=1270)

Answer (score 2):

On a weekday, this question is a non-starter: the onen is prohibited from making any blessing at all. (Shulchan Aruch Y.D. 241:1)

On Shabbos, when the *onen* is permitted to attend the synagogue, Rebbi Akiva Eiger (to Y.D. 241:1) believes that he is nevertheless prohibited from getting an *aliyah*, as he is not allowed to study Torah. (I'm not sure if this is true according to the Dagul MeRvavah to Magen Avraham O.C. 548:8 who writes that an onen is permitted to learn Torah).

Shaarei Efraim (9:111) writes that if an avel was called to the Torah by mistake, then he should accept the aliyah, as refusing would constitute a public display of mourning. I would imagine that R. Margolios would say the same regarding an onen.

Rav Yitzchak Yosef writes (Yalkut Yosef, Bikur Cholim v'Aveilus 7:65) that on Simchas Torah, when everyone in the shul is accustomed to receiving an aliyah, the onen may receive one as well, because avoiding it indicates a public display of mourning, which is prohibited on Yom Tov.

Comment: "a public display of mourning" Is Aninut mourning, such that it's prohibited to display it on Shabbat, or does it not apply on Shabbat simply because you can't deal with the burial? Note Aninut sets in before Shabbat ends if you are going to be Makhshich on the Techum.

Comment: @DoubleAA true (at least according to one opinion in the Rosh, which we probably pasken like), aninus doesn't apply purely because one is not dealing with the burial, but R. Ovadiah assumes that the prohibition of displaying signs of mourning publicly applies to aninus as well. Also, even if aninus is not mourning per se, if there's a prohibition to learn Torah, it is probably due to an extension of the laws of mourning (as Ramban writes in Toras HaAdam regarding washing etc.). But I admit these points are not so solid